# Android java.lang.NullPointerException during a SQLiteDatabase .execSQL

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I have a DbHelper class that extend SQLiteOpenHelper and trying to create a db upgrade system on the method **onUpgrade()**, but during the execution of the very first query it trhow a NullPointerException

My onUpgrade code is:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        SysLog("upgrading Db from "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion);
        if (db == null){
            ErrorLog("Errore nel Db", "db is null");
            $.finish();
            return;
        }
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            int i = oldVersion;
            if (oldVersion != newVersion){
                exportDB();
            }
            while(i < newVersion){
                ArrayList<String> qs = getSqlAlterDb(i);
                for (int z = 0; z < qs.size(); z++){
                    SysLog(qs.get(z));
                    db.execSQL(qs.get(z));
                }
                i++;
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch (Exception e){
            ErrorLog(e);
        }finally {
            if (db.inTransaction()) {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
```

And this is my error log:

```
W/System.err: ---------[|__java.lang.NullPointerException]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.database.DatabaseUtils.getSqlStatementType(DatabaseUtils.java:1363)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1781)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1725)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__wproject.barcodegest.db.DbHelper.onUpgrade(DbHelper.java:177)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__wproject.barcodegest.db.DbManager.query(DbManager.java:306)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__wproject.barcodegest.widget.user.UserGestorObj.inizialize(UserGestorObj.java:76)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__wproject.barcodegest.widget.user.UserGestorObj.<init>(UserGestorObj.java:57)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__wproject.barcodegest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)]
W/System.err: ---------[    |__dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)]
```

I have already tested the version, if db is null or if the query is null. I have everything that is required or that i know how to test. I'm sure qs.get() return a coerent query. And i'm sure db is not null. As the log says, the problem seems to come from the DatabaseUtils when i try to get the state of the db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `qs.get(z)`... What is it? Seems to be null

Comment: Post your query

Comment: please print content of qs.get(z) looks like you are getting a null object

Comment: The above line, (SysLog(qs.get(z));) is my custom system log and don't give null, correctly print a coerent query. Also the null pointer come from DatabaseUtils.java:1363. If qs.get return null it must come from DbHelper, or i'm wrong?

Comment: @Zoronel Yes, wrong: The JVM wouldn't throw a NPE if you pass a `null` as a parameter; that's legal. It only would throw NPE if you try to de-reference a null reference: I.E.: if you try to invoke some method on a null reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the source code of [DatabaseUtils.getStatementType](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.1_r1.1/core/java/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#1362), the only possible cause of a NPE in that method would be that the received parameter `sql` *is* null. Review your `qs` list's contents, and try some defensive programming to ensure that no nulls are sent as a parameter:

```
String sql=qs.get(z);
if (sql!=null)
{
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Comment: No need to strap yourself, my friend. Everyone can make mistakes.